# Updating docstring in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to contribute to the documentation of the [dask project](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/).
I want to add `pandas` reference as suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2589).
I'm able to rebuild the documentation on my developer machine - but I cannot see any changes in the documentation when I update the `docstring`.
For example, I'm trying to add `:meth:pandas.{reader}` to update the `READ_DOC_TEMPLATE` in the [csv.py](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py) but nothing is updated.
I tried to do a simple update of the `docstring` (i.e. change the wording of the docstring) but nothing changes (even if I run the `make clean`).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

thx

Comment: Could it be that you already have dask installed on your system and that Sphinx is extracting docstrings from that version instead of the clone that you are working on?

Comment: I'm running from within a `conda virtual environment`, as suggested from the docs README file. and when I alter the `docs/source/dataframe-api.rst` file I do see the html updated. Still no changes when I update the `READ_DOC_TEMPLATE`.

Comment: As @mzjn alluded, when you update a docstring, are you updating the copy that you cloned or the copy in the installed package? Sphinx will build docs from the latter. When you edit the cloned copy, you should reinstall the local edited copy. `cd` to the parent directory of your package, then whatever the command equivalent is for conda to [`pip install -e .`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-e).

Comment: Seems like my hunch was correct: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4317#issuecomment-353772813

Answer (score 1):

As @mzjn commented:
The solution was to update (uncomment) the `conf.py` with the following line:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))
```