# Sphinx won't update html page when python file is updated

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am having an issue where Sphinx won't update the html page when my python file is updated.

My `docs folder` look like this:
[image]

The `api.rst` file in the folder above looks like this:

```
API Documentation
=================

This is a documentation for the Helstrom Quantum Centroid (HQC) classifier's API.

.. automodule:: hqc.HQC
    :members:
```

The `hqc folder` looks like this:
[image]

Both the `docs folder` and the `hqc folder` are in the same `HQC folder`.

When I update the `HQC.py` file and run `make html` in the command prompt, the html page won't update itself.

But I noticed that when I change the folder name from `hqc` to a new folder name, say `hqc1` (and change `hqc.HQC` to `hqc1.HQC` in the `api.rst` file too), then the html page updates when I run `make html`.

What am I missing or how do I fix this? Would really prefer the `hqc folder` name to stay as `hqc`.

Comment: `make clean && make html` should purge the build and rebuild docs. If you do not see updates that you expect, check your `conf.py` for the location of your build. Finally make sure that the package you want to document is in fact a Python package (contains an `__init__.py` file) and is included in your python in your `conf.py`.

Comment: Perhaps you already have HQC installed and Sphinx is extracting docstrings from that version instead of the clone that you are currently working on. You may need to add a `sys.path.insert` entry in conf.py. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46264706/407651.

Comment: Hi @mzjn, I have added `sys.path.insert` but it didn't work. But you had pointed to something @Steve Piercy had mentioned in your link which could be it.

Comment: Hi @Steve Piercy (and @mzjn), according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264706/updating-docstring-in-sphinx), you mentioned that "when you update a docstring, are you updating the copy that you cloned or the copy in the installed package? Sphinx will build docs from the latter. When you edit the cloned copy, you should reinstall the local edited copy.", do you mean if I have a copy installed in pip, I will need to update docstrings in this copy in pip first as Sphinx builds on docs in pip?

Comment: Is this still a problem? I notice that you use `.. automodule:: hqc.HQC` in the question. On Github, you have `.. automodule:: HQC.HQC` (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leockl/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier/master/docs/api.rst).

Comment: Hi @mzjn, I couldn't find a solution to the problem, so I decided to rename the folder to HQC (rather than hqc which is still what prefer if there was a solution as I am unsure if this will have any downstream effect as when I uploaded my package into pip, I am still using a hqc folder rather than a HQC folder). Do you know where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: You may find the [-a and -E](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-a) build flags handy when Sphinx isn't picking up source changes.

Answer (score 4):

Happens sometimes when sphinx doesn't recognize the changes, use `make clean && make html`, this will first delete all existing files and then create new ones.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you suggested but it didn't work. Any other suggestions I could try and see?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if this is connected, but I have been getting this warning message (which is not in red, just the usual grey): `writing additional pages...  searchc:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\sphinx_rtd_theme\search.html:20: RemovedInSphinx30Warning: To modify script_files in the theme is deprecated. Please insert a <script> tag directly in your theme instead.`

Comment: If it helps, my `conf.py` file looks like the below:

Comment: The "Options for HTML output" part

Comment: # -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'

# Add any paths that contain custom themes here, relative to this directory.
html_theme_path = [sphinx_rtd_theme.get_html_theme_path()]

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
html_static_path = ['_static']

# Output file base name for HTML help builder.
htmlhelp_basename = 'HQCdoc'

Comment: if `make clean` followed by `make html` did not help, I really have no clue what's wrong

Comment: The RemovedInSphinx30Warning is probably not related to the main problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57402446/407651.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with the same problem and, in my case, the issue was that *sphinx* was looking at an older version of my module installed locally.

Two things worked for me:

1. Install my module with the `-e` flag:

`pip install -e .`

2. Set the `PYTHONPATH` to point directly at my module when calling `make`:

`PYTHONPATH=<path/to/your/module> make html`

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have a copy of your package installed then it'll always try to fetch the source code from the package which is installed and present in python\Lib folder.
you can check if it's installed or not by running

```
pip list
```

So changing the code of your package which is present locally won't be helpful, so try to change the code of the package which is present in pythons lib folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to reinstall sphinx into a new virtual environment (pyenv or conda) and rerun `make clean html` it should work. It did for me.  Also make sure that you specify correctly the path to your python directory in `conf.py`. If `conf.py` is in `docs` and your python directory is located at the same level as `docs` then run:
`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))`